# How to implement a struct in Rust that has a list of itself as a field

Tags: struct, rust

I have started out learning Rust and is currently trying to write a small neural network as personal exercise. I want to define a struct for my forthcoming Layers/Clusters/Groups of nodes. My initial definition looks like this:

```
struct Layer {
    name: String,  // Human readable name
    id: String,  // UUID in the future
    order: u8,  // int for sorting
    width: u8,  // Number of nodes
    input: [&'Self],  // References to other Layers that feed input into this
}
```

The thing I am struggling with is the `input` field which should contain a list of references to other Layer-instances. I will know at compile time how many each Layer will have in the list so it wont have to me mutable. Is it possible to do this? I cant find a solution on the Google machine or in "the book".

Please advise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it possible to do this? I cant find a solution on the Google machine or in "the book".

Possible yes, though I would not recommend it.

Let's start with the possible: `&Self` would be a "layer reference" with an unnamed lifetime, a lifetime name is for the form `'<symbol>`, so when you write `&'Self` you're specifying a reference of lifetime `'Self`, but you're never specifying the *type* being refered to, which is why rustc complains about "expected type".

If you add a "proper" lifetime name, and parametrize the structure, it compiles fine:

```rust
struct Layer<'sublayers> {
    name: String,  // Human readable name
    id: String,  // UUID in the future
    order: u8,  // int for sorting
    width: u8,  // Number of nodes
    input: [&'sublayers Self],  // References to other Layers that feed input into this
}
```

*However* I would not recommend it as the last member being a slice means it's a [DST](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/exotic-sizes.html#dynamically-sized-types-dsts) which are difficult to work with at the best of time -- as the nomicon specifically notes "custom DSTs are a largely half-baked feature for now".

Since Rust doesn't yet have const generics proper you can't use an array you'd parameterize through `layer` either (e.g. `Layer<const Size>` and `input: [&Self;Size]`, maybe one day), so you probably want something like a vector or a slice reference e.g.

```rust
struct Layer<'slice, 'sublayers: 'slice> {
    name: String,  // Human readable name
    id: String,  // UUID in the future
    order: u8,  // int for sorting
    width: u8,  // Number of nodes
    input: &'slice [&'sublayers Self],  // References to other Layers that feed input into this
}
```

Comment: +1 for a vector. Often ownership is not significantly more expensive, `Vec<&'sublayers Self>` or even `Vec<Self>`. But of course it depends.

Comment: You don't necessarily need two lifetimes: `&'sublayers [&'sublayers Self]` will usually work in cases like this.